# How do I remove time duration as outliers from a column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, outliers

I want to remove outliers from a datetime columns after applying difference between two datetime to get the duration. I applied boxplot to get the outliers, but, I cannot remove the outliers from the new duration column. here is the code.

```
df['tpep_pickup_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['tpep_pickup_datetime'])
df['tpep_dropoff_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['tpep_dropoff_datetime'])

df['trip duration'] = df['tpep_dropoff_datetime'] -df['tpep_pickup_datetime']
# convert time duration to integer.
df['trip duration'] = int(df['trip duration'].dp.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')) 
for the distance column
fig = plt.figure(figsize =(10, 7))
plt.boxplot(df['trip_distance'])
plt.show()
# for the duration column
fig = plt.figure(figsize =(10, 7))
plt.boxplot(df['trip duration'])
plt.show()


# drop the outliers

df_2= df[df['trip_distance'] < 6] 

df_2= df[df['trip duration'] > 0]
 
TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=timedelta64[ns] and int
```

I am trying to convert the duration column to inttype but I can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas is expecting you to provide a unit, or else the comparision is meaningless. You can use timedelta to provide a unit.

```
from datetime import timedelta

df_2= df[df['trip duration'] > timedelta(hours=0)]
```